# Change text encoding to No Explicit in localizable file

Tags: ios, xcode10

Currently my `text encoding` of the Localizable.strings file is set to `UTF-8`. All my other localizable files are set to `no explicit`.

I want to change `UTF-8` to `No explicit`, how is it possible ?

If you want to know, it's cause with xCode 10 this error appears

> could not decode input file using specified encoding: Unicode (UTF-8), and the file contents appear to be encoded in Unicode (UTF-16)

[image]

Comment: You could try manually editing the `project.pbxproj` file to remove the `fileEncoding = x` for your Localizable.strings file?

Comment: @IanL That's a good answer. Thx (post for accepting answer)

Comment: In case anyone else has the same problem as me... you might end up in this position because you had the error that it was not encoded as UTF-8 and so you tried changing the encoding, but the underlying issues was you have a missing semi-colon at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try manually editing the `project.pbxproj` file to remove the `fileEncoding = x` for your `Localizable.strings` file?

Answer (score 1):

To reset the `Text-Encoding` type. Select your language.string file:

[image]

**Then select `Text Encoding` from right hand panel:**

[image]

**Update:**

If you accidentally selected the `Text-Encoding`, then you have to reset it from `project.pbxproj`. To do this follow below steps:

1. Open package content of your `Project.xcodeproj`

[image]

2. Open `project.pbxproj` and search for your file-name and remove the `fileEncoding = <encoding>;` (for example: `fileEncoding = 4;`), and save the file.

[image]

Comment: Hello, the option doesn't exist in the list (image added)

Comment: I think you are selecting main `Localizable.string` file. Please expand this file, it will show separate file for all language and then select one file at a time.

Comment: @Makaille, Updated the answer for reset it to `No Explicit Encoding`.